# not able to print pound sign in meta description tag

Tags: php, html

I am trying to print the prices of products on product page in meta description tag but i m not able to print pound sign with price in meta description tag  which is as follows

```
echo '<meta name="description" content="Buy '.$title.' at '&pound'.'.$price.'">';
```

But its printing &pound in text in meta description tag but i want it to be a pound sign with price
price and title are variables naming price and name coming from database which are displayed correctly..
Please help on hpw to display pound sign in meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

The character reference needs a semi-colon after it:

```
&pound;
```

Or just use the actual character:

```
£
```

---

You also need to get your string correct. You have extra `'` characters.

It is usually easier to keep your HTML outside PHP mode and only echo the variables.

```
<meta name="description" 
     content="Buy <?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?>  at £<?php echo htmlspecialchars($price); ?>">
```

Comment: How are you testing this? (If you are looking at the source code, then it should look like `&pound;`, because that is how you are expressing the character in the source)

Comment: I am checking in view source,but in console of chrome,its coming as pound sign correctly.But i think for seo i need to view source code ,isnt it?

Comment: The source code matters to SEO in the same way that it matters to browsers. They read the source code and understand what HTML means.